# Lenz's law problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image]
When switch is closed the ring will jump upward, but why?

I know that when the switch is closed a current is established in the solenoid. The current flow is from + to - so that the direction of the magnetic field in the solenoid is downward (according to right hand rule). The magnetic flux increases according to Lenz's law. So, the ring should produce a magnetic field in the opposite direction. In my book it is stated that the ring will feel a force upward. I know that the induced current which is in a magnetic field will experience a force but I don't know how to identify the direction of this force. How can I know that it's upward; which rule should I use?

Comment: Hi Elize and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I am not asking for homework check my question is how can I find the direction of a force which a ring would feel when it is located in a changing magnetic flux just I need the rule

Comment: See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html

Comment: Following @sammygerbil link (Lorentz Force), I think you also need to assume that the magnetic field is not pointing ***directly downwards*** near the ring. Rather, the field is downwards and radial (inward). The ***radial component*** is the one that will push the ring upwards. Possibly, the graded top construction of the iron core is meant to emphasize this field orientation.

Comment: What is radial component ?I haven't seen such a thing as radial component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider a circular current carrying loop as a bar magnet. The coils of the solenoid can be simplified as a bar magnet with north pointing down (As magnetic field is down). And the ring as a bar magnet with north pointing up(As the induced current has a magnetic field up). They clearly repel.